# Incompatibility of two dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry

In my program I try to connecte to two servers. Both connexions work perfectely when they are in different projetcs. However, when they are in the same maven projet, i got an exception during the connexion.

In my case, when i add this dependecy in my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.35</version>
</dependency>
```

I can connecte to amazon server without problem. But, I cannot connect to another server (Cloud Foundary in my case).  I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3eb77ea8; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3eb77ea8; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:417)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.java:47)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.oauth2.OauthClient.getToken(OauthClient.java:66)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.login(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:626)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.login(CloudFoundryClient.java:149)
    at telecom.sudparis.eu.paas.core.server.ressources.manager.application.TestErrors.main(TestErrors.java:27)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3eb77ea8; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:716)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2158)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:123)
    ... 10 more
```

However, When I remove this dependency I don't have a problem for connexion to Cloud Foudary. But, I got an errors for aws class that I use.

My question is. How can I add both dependencies without having this exception ?

Comment: This discussion may help you, I hope (Jackson versions compatibility between Spring and CloudFoundry) : https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/140

Comment: @Berger Thanks a lot. It works ;)